Cell fracture using annotate not working
So I wanted to create broken glass and do a rigid body simulation. I used the annotate tool and using the project to surface feature, drew a couple of bullet holes. When I proceeded to use the cell fracture add on, it displayed the error in the screenshot. I opened up a new file and tried it but nothing changed. I couldn't find a solution anywhere and pretty much all the tutorials I watched online were doing the steps I did, but their cell fracture add on was working flawlessly instead of displaying an error like in my case. What should I do?

It would have been helpful to see this screenshot you are talking about. Also the scene with the object you want to fracture and the annotations. And probably the Cell Fracture settings as well?
